# 400 Bad Request while querying base on Solr 5.5 + Tomcat 8

Tags: solr, tomcat8

The error happens when clicking "Execute Query" btn, below is the request url captured on chrome network console:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/core0%2Fselect?_=1458631537955&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json
```

if i manually change to below url (**%2F** to **"/"**), the request fires correctly.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/core0/select?_=1458631537955&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json
```

Not sure why, any idea would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: any error in the server logs?

Comment: Tomcat is not a supported configuration for Solr 5.5. You are probably getting some unexpected double-escape somewhere in between the two.